# Hide dynamically generated button in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to Hide dynamically generated button in react native
Below is  my code. I have used **overflow: hidden** but it is not working.

```
renderSeats() {        
    var seats = [];
    var columnCount = 2;

    for(var index = 0; index < columnCount; index++) {
        var title = (index + 1).toString();
        var isDisabled = false, isHidden = false;
        if(title == 1) {
            isDisabled = true;            
            isHidden = false;

        }               
        if(isHidden)
            seats.push(  

                <View hide={this.state.isHidden}>
                    <Button title={title} style={{overflow: "hidden"}} disabled={isDisabled}></Button>   
                </View>          
                );
        else
        seats.push(
                <View style={{overflow: "hidden"}}>
                    <Button title={title} style={{overflow: "hidden"}} disabled={isDisabled}></Button>
                </View>
                );
    }           

    return seats;
}
```

Comment: `visiblity: hidden` ?

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden` is meant for content that is overflowing.

You can try `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. However, this might not work for react-native either.

**Instead you can just not render it:**

```
if ( !isHidden ) {
  seats.push( <withButton> )
}
```